# ArrayList.get() returns pointer not value?

Tags: java, arraylist, get

Does ArrayList.get(index) return only the value of the element at index or a pointer to this element? I ask this because this doesn't perform as I expect it to

```
List<List<Integer>> myList; 
myList = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(n, new ArrayList<>()));
           .
           .
           .
List tempList = this.myList.get(x);
tempList.add(i);
this.myList.set(i,tempList);
```

Instead of adding an element to the array at index x, and storing the new list at index i, it is appending the element at both spots so instead of a list increasing in size, I get n times the last element

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1 ?  See if that answers your question.

Comment: ALL Java variables of object type are references, which behave very much like pointers.

Comment: I searched but didn't see this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong place.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with this code:

```
List tempList = this.myList.get(x);
tempList.add(i);
this.myList.set(i,tempList);
```

except that it can be abbreviated to this:

```
List tempList = this.myList.get(x);
tempList.add(i);
```

(and except that you are using `List`, which is a raw data type, which also means that you do not have warnings enabled, but that's another story.)

Your problem is here:

```
myList = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(n, new ArrayList<>()));
```

If you look at the implementation of `Collections.nCopies()` you will see that it internally uses a special list which contains ***only one element***, the element that you gave it, and no matter which index you request, it returns to you that same original element.

So, you do not have `n` lists to begin with;  you only have one list.